# Create a dataset with a stored procedure with two databases for rdlc report VS2015

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, dataset, rdlc

I want add a new Datasets to my rdlc report in VS 2015, so I created a new data source with my stored procedure. There it is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAccidents]
(@p_anneeDebut date, @p_anneeFin date)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM T_ACCIDENT
LEFT OUTER JOIN TJ_ACC_PAR ON TJ_ACC_PAR.ACC_id = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_id AND TJ_ACC_PAR.ACC_type = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_type AND TJ_ACC_PAR.ACC_annee = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_annee
LEFT OUTER JOIN TR_PARTIE_CORPS ON TJ_ACC_PAR.PAR_id = TR_PARTIE_CORPS.PAR_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TR_BLESSURE ON TJ_ACC_PAR.BLE_id = TR_BLESSURE.BLE_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ERP.dbo.TR_COST_CENTER ON TR_COST_CENTER.COS_id = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_lieuPrecis
WHERE ACC_date <= @p_anneeFin AND ACC_date >= @p_anneeDebut
```

But when I add this new data source, it does not appears in the list "Data Source" so I can't select it for my report. ( The data source is well created ).

I tested with other stored procedure and it works, the problem is this line (because without this line it works too) :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ERP.dbo.TR_COST_CENTER ON TR_COST_CENTER.COS_id = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_lieuPrecis
```

Because this line call an other database but the query works in SQL SERVER.
How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running you stored proc from the Sql server, maybe its the Collation between the two databases which is different, that is if the join is on a string value. If you are calling a stored proc in SSRS the best trouble shoot is to first get the results in SSMS and if an error comes up you can easily troubleshoot. Plus try using alias on your Joins.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried the query in Sql server and it works. I tried with alias on my joins but it does not work too